# Pandas iterrows very slow

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need some help with replacing `iterrows` in iterating over a Pandas dataframe.
I have a Pandas dataframe like this one:

```
| cust_no | channel  | month1 | month2 |
|   1     | radio    | 0.7    | 0.4    |
|   1     | fb       | 0.1    | 0.5    |
|   1     | tv       | 0.2    | 0.1    |
|   2     | fb       | 0.5    | 0.25   |
|   2     | radio    | 0.4    | 0.25   |
|   2     | tv       | 0.1    | 0.5    |
```

I need the channel that has the maximum value for each month when grouped by cust_no, and join them as a string in a new column in the same dataframe. So, for example, from above dataframe:

In Customer 1's case `radio` has max value in month1, but `fb` has the max value in month 2, so I need this string: `radio>fb`

In customer 2's case `fb` has max value in month1, but `tv` has the max value in month2, so I need this strong: `fb>tv`

Appreciate any help. Thanks. `Performance is really important`

Comment: [OBLIGATORY WARNING](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/4909087), don't use `iterrows` to iterate over a dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create index by `channel` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and last use  `apply+join`:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('channel')
         .groupby('cust_no')['month1','month2']
         .idxmax()
         .apply('>'.join, axis=1)
         .reset_index(name='new'))
print (df1)
   cust_no       new
0        1  radio>fb
1        2     fb>tv
```

If no another columns is posible remove filtering columns `month1` and `month2`:

```
df1 = (df.set_index('channel')
         .groupby('cust_no')
         .idxmax()
         .apply('>'.join, axis=1)
         .reset_index(name='new'))
print (df1)
   cust_no       new
0        1  radio>fb
1        2     fb>tv
```

Comment: Thanks! this is great... it didn't occur to me to use channel as index.